# Programming CUDA architecture

Tags: cuda

During programming on CUDA architecture I faced a problem: device resources are too limited. In other words, the stack and heap are too small.

While researching about it, I found a function 
`cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitStackSize, limit_stack)`
that enlarges the stack size, and a similar one for the heap. Although, their dimensions are still too limited.

I wonder how can I store more information on the device?

Comment: Can you show some code to describe what you want to achieve? It is unusual that you need change the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack and heap are provided for convenience. However, you may allocate memory using cudaMalloc on the device if your gpu is recent enough. In that case, the limit is the gpu on-board memory.

Should you want more, you would need a custom memory allocation managing a large array of system memory, and sharing it with the gpu (see cudaHostRegister). Then, the limit would be your system memory.

Comment: Thank you. Until now I used cudaHostAlloc. I'll try cudaHostRegister function.